# Is it possible make a xib file via shell?

Tags: xcode, macos, shell

Is it possible to create a xib file via shell? I tried to search for documentations about xcodebuild, ibtool, etc., but I can't find this type of option

Comment: i dont think so... why would you want to do that? what content would you want it to have?

Comment: I'm developing a command line tool with I create basic swift files, etc... like artisan  in Laravel

Comment: I don't think it is possible, xcode does alot when creating nib files

Comment: I think I found a way, a xib file is basically a xml inside. So I tried to make xml file with .xib and for now everything is working